# Groovy map - keys with space

Tags: groovy, maps, whitespace, getter

I have a map in groovy that looks like the following...

```
def book = [Title of Book: "Groovy Recipes", Author: "Scott Davis", Number of Pages: "241"]
```

I add my each 'book' into a BookList and would like to be able to get each value later on but when I try something like...

```
BookList.Title of Book[0] //prints something like Title[0] instead of Groovy Recipes
```

So my question is, is there a way to get those key/values without changing the names of the keys?

Comment: The question is about _accessing_ the values, but I'm puzzled by how you _initialized_ the map.  To get that to compile, I needed to put quotes around the keys: `def book = ["Title of Book": "Groovy Recipes",...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked in the groovy shell. You just have to use the `[]` instead of the dot notation:

```
groovy:000> map = [:]
===> {}
groovy:000> map['Title of Book'] = "Adam Riese"
===> Adam Riese
groovy:000> map
===> {Title of Book=Adam Riese}
```

Comment: Unacceptable. Need to be able to do `= [ "Title of Book": "Adam Riese" ]` or `= [ ["Title of Book"]: "Adam Riese" ]`.